# Can you help me with framework choice?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, frameworks

I'm thinking about developing an app which will make a strong use of geolocation (mongodb will be my choice), and strong upload of photos (and viewing too).

I was just wondering if you could help me with framework election. I've been using node.js for months and I'm very comfortable with it, but because of its one-process nature, will it be bad for locking when uploading big photos?

The other solution I'm working on is rails.

Which one will you choose? Any other ?

Thanks

Comment: Using 1 process with Rails gives you the same problem. You need to scale. Using Rails that would be to run multiple Rails instances (1 instance per process).

Comment: yeah, I know that. But I thought that it was easier to scale rails apps. But I don't know, thats why I'm asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Streaming you can support more then one client during a upload, since the upload will be broken into different parts. I sure expressjs has some good streaming examples.

Comment: streaming is a node js module or what? thanks!

Comment: Here is a plain node example:
http://debuggable.com/posts/streaming-file-uploads-with-node-js:4ac094b2-b6c8-4a7f-bd07-28accbdd56cb

Comment: And here is a example using socket.io: http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2012/02/11/12-pushing-files-to-the-browser-using-deliveryjs-socketio-and-nodejs/

Answer (score 1):

> ... but because of its one-process nature, will it be bad for locking when uploading big photos?

Take a look at the [`cluster` module](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html), this should help with leveraging more cores. In fact one of the node.js clients on the front page are these guys: [Transloadit](https://transloadit.com/) who focus on handling images.

> I'm thinking about developing an app which will make a strong use of geolocation (mongodb will be my choice)...

I've done a lot of work with MongoDB and I recommend reading up on the limitations of MongoDB's geo-location tools. The product does provide some functionality, but it does not match the features of Postgres. You will want to ensure that MongoDB covers all of the features you require before beginning.

Comment: FOr what I'm thinking mongodb is perfect. But if you could tell me some of its drawbacks =)

Comment: Any way, I've heard bad things about cluster module, and that it's not mature enough, how about that?